# Automation process for uploading image to the web site from computer folder in Python

Tags: python, automation, webdriver

I am trying to upload image from the folder on my PC, and the problem is- I cannot use send_keys as it should be uploaded from the list of images from the folder. Please see attached photo and code:

```
def picture(self):
  path = "/home/nataliya/Desktop/dog.png"
  editPhoto = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//* [@id="easSettingAvatarUpload"]')
  editPhoto.click()
  time.sleep(2)
  editPhoto.send_keys(path)
  editPhoto.submit()
```

[image: screenshot for the folder]

Error I get: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Answer (score 0):

I was calling a wrong thing :)
That worked:

```
    path = "/home/nataliya/Desktop/cat.jpg"
    editPhoto = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="easSettingAvatarUpload"]')
    time.sleep(2)
    editPhoto.send_keys(path)
    time.sleep(2)
```